# Screenshot the entire web-page

Tags: macos, screen-capture

In macOS, one can easily get a screen capture by using key combination <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>.

But, are there any keyboard shortcuts that can scroll a webpage or any other pages and get the screen capture?

I am looking for a keyboard shortcut and not an app or browser extension that needs to be downloaded from the Internet or Mac App Store.

Answer (score 22):

**Safari now has a ScreenCapture feature built-in**, as explained in the article [Full Page Screenshots in Browsers](https://css-tricks.com/full-page-screenshots-browsers/#article-header-id-2):

> In Safari DevTools, select a node, right-click, and you'll see Capture Screenshot in the context menu.

There isn't a keyboard shortcut AFAIK, but it is available without additional third-party software. To capture the entire page, you would right-click on the `<html>` or `<body>` node, as demonstrated in this image from the CSS-Tricks article:

[image: Demonstration of the Capture Screenshot feature in Safari]

Comment: This is awesome!

Comment: This is the correct answer IMO, use CMD+Option+I to bring up Developer Tools in Safari

Comment: As @DaveNelson said ⌥⌘I brings up Developer Tools, but for this shortcut to work you first need to enable the developer menu in Safari → Settings → Advanced

Answer (score 11):

**Update**: Safari introduced a feature accessible via the developer tools, which lets users capture screenshot of the entire webpage. This feature was not available at the time the answer was written. The original answer is kept as is for reference.

For Safari, refer to the answer by [shawncampbell](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/361632/279727).

> But, are there any keyboard shortcuts that can scroll a webpage or any other pages and get the screen capture?

No, there's no built-in mechanism in Safari/macOS to scroll and screenshot an entire webpage.

You'll either need to manually scroll, snap and stitch the images or write a script, both of which could be cumbersome.

You can do a Web search and find 3rd party Safari extensions that can perform this function for you, but again that's not what you are looking for.

If you relax the scope and are willing to download a software from the Internet, you can install [Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/), a popular alternative Web browser for macOS. A screenshot tool, aptly named [Firefox Screenshots](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/firefox-screenshots) is natively built into the web browser.

Download and install Firefox, open the desired Web page, click on the **Page actions** button in the address bar and select **Take a Screenshot** option.

[image]

You can choose between capturing the **entire page**,just the **visible area** or a **specific region** within the visible area.

[image]

What's great is that you can choose between downloading the generated image right away or save them online for later access (Do note that as per the linked [support article](https://support.mozilla.org/kb/firefox-screenshots), screenshots are saved for 14 days only). You can also copy the image directly to the clipboard or edit it in the browser itself.

[image]

Here's the **[Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com)** Web page in it's full glory :)

[image]

In my opinion, this is the most hassle free approach one can take to screenshot a Web page in macOS.

Comment: Plus 1 just for th effort of the full page shown : way to go! But good answer anyway.

Comment: Wow! A reason to use Firefox! I haven’t had one of those in a decade! Cool to know this feature exists. 

Comment: I wish I knew this method of a full page-length screenshot. Makes certain aspects of web scraping WAY more efficient. I've scraped over 50k entities...

Comment: Nimesh - [long long man](https://www.theverge.com/tldr/2018/4/6/17207904/long-long-man-meme-sakeru-gum-japan-commercial) would upvote your answer, I’m sure of it.

Comment: @bmike Ha ha, nice!

Comment: The first sentence says, "there's no built-in mechanism in Safari/macOS to… screenshot an entire webpage."

That may have been true when this answer was written, but the answer from @shawncampbell clearly shows that this feature is now built-in to Safari. (Albeit hidden in DevTools.)

Comment: @StevenKlein You are absolutely right. I have updated my answer by adding a note. I have [acknowledged](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334689/screenshot-entire-web-page/334724?noredirect=1#comment479580_361632) Shawn's answer the day it was posted.

Answer (score 3):

Run `brew install webkit2png` and then run a command like this:

```
webkit2png -F -W 1280 https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334689/screenshot-entire-web-page
```

`-F` creates a full-size screenshot. `-W` changes the width of the browser window (the default is 800).

Answer (score 2):

Understanding the OP doesn’t want third party tools, many others will want this, so there are a couple of easy ways to do this using a mac.

- [Paparazzi! app](https://derailer.org/paparazzi/) - opens a window. Just paste the URL to capture the entire web page. The File menu has "Save Image As" to save the whole web page. With tools like folder actions, you can then print, file, or do whatever you wish with the images.
- Web sites provide this service as well - no software required. One is [web-capture.net](https://web-capture.net). Also, paste your URL to receive an image type of your choosing. This easily prints or downloads as a zip file.
- [Awesome Screen Capture](https://safari-extensions.apple.com/?q=Awesome%20screenshot) is an extension that provides a simple way to capture the entire website.

Comment: The link for `Awesome Screen Capture` seems to be broken. I 'm getting `Http/1.1 Service Unavailable`

Answer (score 1):

I managed to take the entire page image of the website (on Safari) by clicking through: File > Export as PDF.

Though not PNG, the PDF did the job for me, since all I really wanted was some form of the capture of the entire webpage.... best!

Comment: You can also add a keyboard shortcut for Export as PDF... (like Command+E, for example) via System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts to make this even faster and more accessible. Resultant screenshots are full-length and can be highlighted, marked up, etc. in Preview.

Answer (score 0):

No. Safari on macos 10.13 and lower doesn’t have this function to scroll and snap and paste and stitch together pages so this isn’t possible. Making a shortcut for an official function is trivial and you could automate everything with a smart enough script and then trigger your tool, but you’re back to adding a third party program at that point.

Best is to perhaps explore if saving as pdf works for you after trying reading mode. Those would be far less work to script into a shortcut or two.

That being said, there are dozens of great options and tools to do this - some as simple as choosing an alternate browser than the one that ships with macOS. As great as Safari is for some things, choice is the blessing of a computer OS like macOS to allow more tools to be made to run on that platform.

Comment: Apple is going about crippling Safari.  I found a reference to Nimbus for safari, but it's no longer in the app store. Nimbus exists for Firefox and it's free.

Comment: Just to note here that histrionics are not only unhelpful, but often untrue. Point-of-fact, not only is Apple striving to improve Safari, but they have added this feature directly into the browser. Helpful to remember next time someone says that the sky is falling because Apple doesn't have feature X right now.

Answer (score 0):

There is another flexible while mostly unwieldy way to do this.
1. recording your all page content with quicktime and save it to a video file
2. export frames as images from the video file with final cut pro x
3. combine all images into a lengthy panorama with photoshop, namely the full screenshot of the page